# iTunes update keeps reappearing even after several updates

Tags: itunes, mac-appstore, software-update

iTunes software update keeps appearing in the app store even after several updates of the same. Has anyone faced a similar issue? When I try to update it, the download begins and installs and again reappears on the App store. Moreover this is happening in my new mac. I'm unable to find the root cause for this issue.

Comment: What happens if you download itunes from the web site (not app store) install the download and then reboot?

Comment: when i try to download it from the web, it gets redirected to Mac app store directly!

Comment: What about if you click the download link on the left here: http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/